# Did something wrong installing/uninstalling MySQL on Lion

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, safari, osx-lion

This is my first post here and it is quite embarrassing, to say the least. I have been having trouble installing MySQL on my new Macbook Air. I installed it (or so I thought) but could not get it to work. I then made the bright decision to uninstall it using these instructions.

http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

I know these are for Leopard and I realize this was a stupid mistake now. After performing the above commands, I reinstalled MySQL and restarted my computer. Upon starting the system, several things had changed:

- The font in Google Chrome is now changed to something with Serifs and I can't seem to change it back
- When I try to use Safari, for most web pages the font will not display. Instead of characters, it displays a graphic similar to [A], but with a square surrounding the A instead of brackets.
- When I open the terminal, instead of displaying 'Jamess-MacBook-Air: jameskatz$ ', it displays 'localhost:~ jameskatz$ ' at the prompt.

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong and if I can do anything to fix it? I am considering reformatting and reinstalling Lion, as I know this will bother me forever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Much thanks in advance,

James

Comment: It sounds like you deleted Helvetica.  Can you link to where you installed MySQL from?

Comment: I downloaded it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=403751#mirrors             I believe I used the U Wisconsin mirror, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Reinstall Lion.  Especially if this is a Macbook Air that is new to you, and you won't have to reinstall a lot of software, this isn't a rabbit hole you probably want to see more of (think 'an eventual Sad-Finder startup screen and inevitable Lion reinstall.').  But hey, at least you get to install it from that neato tiny USB chip and watch the install take fifteen minutes thanks to the SSD!